# Can't update on 18.04 - Custom Repository Change

Tags: 18.04, repository, apt-mirror

I have Custom Repository for my personal packages.

Today, after running sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade, I saw:

```
Get:1 http://XXX/ubuntu-custom bionic/ InRelease [2,061 B]
E: Repository 'http://XXX/ubuntu-custom bionic/ InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'ubuntu-custom' to 'root'
E: Repository 'http://XXX/ubuntu-custom bionic/ InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'ubuntu-custom' to 'root'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]
```

I know if I run "apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change" I can resolve the problem ...

But why it happens and how I could solve it in my mirror-server